# Class has no instance method `call`

Tags: flutter, dart

I receive the following `NoSuchMethodError` in my code:

```
I/flutter ( 6579): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
I/flutter ( 6579): Class 'List<DocumentSnapshot>' has no instance method 'call'.
I/flutter ( 6579): Receiver: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList'
I/flutter ( 6579): Tried calling: call(0)
```

This is the error line:

```
return RepTile(RepData.fromDocument(snapshot.data.documents(index)));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is that your are using **parentheses `()`** to access an element in your `List`, which tries to invoke `call` on your object, but since your object is not a function, this throws an error.

However, `List` uses **square brackets `[]`** to [access objects at a given index](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/List/operator_get.html).

This means that it is an easy fix, just replace your parentheses by square brackets:

```dart
return RepTile(RepData.fromDocument(snapshot.data.documents[index]));
```