# Trying to push to different viewControllers/view based on what button is pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and am struggling with what seems to be a simple thing.

I have a few buttons in my view, each corresponding to a different (view controller) widget. Depending on what button is pressed I would like to navigate to the corresponding view.

Please see below for a better explanation.

```
Future navigateToPage(context, vc) async {

  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => vc()));
}

class CircularView extends StatelessWidget {

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    StatelessWidget vc;

    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    Widget bigCircle = Container(
      width: (width * 0.9),
      height: (height * 0.5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    );

    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            bigCircle,
                Positioned(
                  child: CustomFloatingActionButton(
                   onPressed: () { 
                      vc = MoneyView(); // < -- Here is where I am assigning the vc variable to a view.
                      navigateToPage(context, vc);
                   },
                buttonType: ButtonType.money,
                    buttonImage: FontAwesomeIcons.moneyBill,
                    label: '',
                  ),
                  top: ((height * 0.5) * 0.175),
                  left: ((width * 0.9) * 0.12),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: CustomFloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                       vc = SchedulesView(); // < ---- And here
                      navigateToPage(context, vc);
                    },
                    buttonType: ButtonType.schedules, 
                    buttonImage: FontAwesomeIcons.database,
                    label: '',
                  ),
                  top: ((height * 0.5) * 0.123),
                  left: ((width * 0.9) * 0.559),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: CustomFloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                       vc = VisitsView; // < ---- And here
                      navigateToPage(context, vc);
                    },
                    buttonType: ButtonType.keyDates, 
                    buttonImage: FontAwesomeIcons.calendar,
                    label: '',
                  ),
                   top: ((height * 0.5) * 0.434),
                   left: ((width * 0.9) * 0.729),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: CustomFloatingActionButton(
                     onPressed: () {
                      vc = RequestsView(); // < ---- And here
                      navigateToPage(context, vc);
                    },
                    buttonType: ButtonType.requests, 
                    buttonImage: FontAwesomeIcons.question,
                    label: '',
                  ),
                  top: ((height * 0.5) * 0.687),
                  left: ((width * 0.76) * 0.53),
                ),
                Positioned(
                   child: CustomFloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      vc = KeyDatesView(); // < ---- And here
                      navigateToPage(context, vc);
                    },
                    buttonType: ButtonType.visits, 
                    buttonImage: FontAwesomeIcons.handshake,
                    label: '',
                  ),
                  top: ((height * 0.5) * 0.53),
                  left: ((width * 0.76) * 0.051),
                ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error I am receiving on the simulator states that the No such method error: 'MoneyView' has no instance method 'call'.

So perhaps I am doing something wrong in the 'MoneyView' class.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Why only the `MoneyView` has **parentheses** `()` and the others not? The only thing I could find is this, and you might want to take a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57207473/class-has-no-instance-method-call).

Comment: Apologies, I have edited them back in (they were formally commented out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the constructor to the **VisitsView** object.
2. Actually don't call the constructor of **vc** object in the lambda of the **navigateToPage** method, cause when you use this function you pass the object inside the function. This is already created object, it doesn't need a constructor.

As advice you can use the named params in your method and functions. It will simplify your life in the future :)