# Allow table with empty cells and rows to be shown or filled - Flutter

Tags: flutter, csv, parsing, tablerow

I have a CSV taken from google analytics, it has empty cells and empty rows. And I am trying to show it in a flutter app. The problem is it won't allow it because of the empty cells.

Get a big red "Table containing irregular row lengths. Every TableRow in a Table must have the same number of children so that every cell is filled. Otherwise, the table will contain holes."

But I want it to be shown, be it with empty holes or filling the empty cells with something.

But how do I do that?
Or is there a way to parse this based on the text?

```
List<List<dynamic>> data = [];
loadAsset() async {

  final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/data/statics.csv");
  List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);

  return csvTable;
}
```

```
class _TableLayoutState extends State<StaticsScreen> {
  void load() async {
    var newdata = await loadAsset();
    setState(() {
      data = newdata;
    });
    print(data);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Statics"),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.refresh), onPressed: load),
      body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
        Table(
          children: data.map((item) {
            return TableRow(
              children: item.map((row) {
                return Text(row.toString());
              }).toList(),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ]),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image: Sample of data from csv]

Tried also to modify the `table.dart` do not have that error, but that breaks the table file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filling the empty cells with something. Try this

Inside your TableRow()

```
 return TableRow(
          children: item.map((row) {
            return Text(row.isEmpty() ? "#" : row.toString());
          }).toList(),
```

Comment: That is probably right for parsing but now something else broke.
Getting a 
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'bool' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: false
Tried calling: call()

Comment: Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57207473/class-has-no-instance-method-call
Looks to be a bracket problem.